# Does vector use move or copy with basic data types ( int, bool, etc )

Tags: c++, c++14

Vector can use a move constructor with a class that has a move constructor that is guaranteed to not throw exception ( noexcept ). However, is that the case for basic data types ( int, bool, etc ) ?

edit : I mean when the vector needs rellocating

Comment: moving a basic type is the same as copying it

Comment: Do you mean to move an element into the vector, or to move one vector's buffer to another? Please clarify. The former was already covered by M.M. The latter can be done regardless of element type as it just involves stealing the pointer to the buffer (and resetting the moved-from instance's size and capacity, etc.)

Comment: I think what he means when underlying array is being expended. Do they use move, copy.

Comment: yep, that is what I meant indeed